# Is there any religious significance for the Invention of Zero?

Tags: numerology

The world knows that Zero was invented/discovered by the Indians. It is profound thought process that led to the birth of Zero / Shunya. I would like to know if there was any part played by the Hinduism in the discovery of Shunya or was it a total random event which could have happened anywhere in the world ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely zero originated from this mantra of Upanishads describing the nature of supreme deity.

> पूर्णमदः पूर्णमिदं पूर्णात्पुर्णमुदच्यते
>   पूर्णश्य पूर्णमादाय पूर्णमेवावशिष्यते ॥
>   ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः
>
> Om Puurnnam-Adah Puurnnam-Idam Puurnnaat-Purnnam-Udacyate
>   Puurnnashya Puurnnam-Aadaaya Puurnnam-Eva-Avashissyate ||
>   Om Shaantih Shaantih Shaantih ||

**Meaning:** Om, That is complete (full, perfect, whole), This is complete (full, perfect, whole), From the completeness comes the completeness If completeness is taken away from completeness, Only completeness remains Om, Peace, peace, peace

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  This is an English-language site; it's fine to quite things from other languages, but you should also provide an English translation.  Also, you should mention which Upanishad it's from.